# Function to build a query string using a loop only returns last loops build string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, text

I have a function that will be used to build a string for a sql query

```
def create_text(tablelist=None, fieldlist=None):
alphalist = []
alpha = 'a'
for i in range(0, len(tablelist)): 
    alphalist.append(alpha) 
    alpha = chr(ord(alpha) + 1) 

for i,v in enumerate(alphalist):
    if i + 1 == len(alphalist):
        last=True
    else:
        last=False
    y=str(v)
    text ="SELECT "+', '.join([y+ '.' +x for x in fieldlist]) + ' FROM ' \
    +str(tablelist[i]) + " as " + str(y)  
    if not last:
        text = text + " UNION ALL"
    print(text)
return text
```

I call it like this

```
text = create_text(tablelist = ['table1', 'table2'], fieldlist = ['v1','v2'])
```

It gives me this output as it prints the string after the second loop

```
SELECT a.v1, a.v2 FROM table1 as a UNION ALL
SELECT b.v1, b.v2 FROM table2 as b
```

However, the value for "text" itself returned from the function, if I just print it

```
print(text)
```

is

```
SELECT b.v1, b.v2 FROM table2 as b
```

This is just the last value in the loop as it overwrites the value for text. I just cant see how to go through the loop and concatenate the text with each iteration so that I get the returned value I want, which is a value for text =

```
"SELECT a.v1, a.v2 FROM table1 as a UNION ALL SELECT b.v1, b.v2 FROM table2 as b"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code redefines `text` inside the loop - so only the last loops iterations text will be returned.

You can clean up your code quite a bit and come to this:

```
def create_text(tablelist=None, fieldlist=None):
    # collects parts to be str.joined later
    parts = []

    # iterate the tablenames directly
    for i, table in enumerate(tablelist):
        # no neeed to precompute, simply use i to get a new alias
        alias = chr(ord('a')+i)  
        # string interpolation style formating for bonus points 
        fields = ', '.join( f"{alias}.{x}" for x in fieldlist)
        # collect in list
        parts.append( f"SELECT {fields} FROM {table} as {alias}")

    # returned joined list
    return " UNION ALL\n".join(parts)

text = create_text(tablelist = ['table1', 'table2'], fieldlist = ['v1','v2'])

print(text)
```

To get

```
SELECT a.v1, a.v2 FROM table1 as a UNION ALL
SELECT b.v1, b.v2 FROM table2 as b
```

Every time you need to concat text, collect them in a list and use `str.join()` - no intermediate strings need to die for string concattenation this way.